# Custom renderer at Xamarin.Forms could find a OnElementChanged method

Tags: xamarin, renderer, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement custom label and iOS renderer for it using Xamarin.Forms.
For some reason [code from sample](http://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-uiviewcontrollers-in-xamarin.forms-on-ios/) is using method which is not in a base class:

> OnElementChanged

[image]

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that Xamarin.Forms SDK referenced by project template by default is not enough.
You have to install additionally NUGET package Xamarin.Forms for your Touch Project:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Change the argument type to `ElementChangedEventArgs`

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

namespace XForms.Toolkit.iOS.Controls
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed but still have compile time error @Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ElementChangedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Sources\LOCAL\App2\App2\App2.iOS\AppDelegate.cs 49 50 App2.iOS - https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tpemfyn9lwak1w/shot_140620_180208.png

Comment: Do you get an option to Resolve it? Did you add the namespaces from the above example?

Comment: no option to resolve, namespace is there: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqeeeso7a727nyd/shot_140623_110648.png

Answer (score 2):

With me, it worked after an update of the Xamarin.Forms Library in the NUGET Package Manager.
But you have to use **ElementChangedEventArgs<>** as Parameter type

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ElementChangedEventArgs < AdMobView > as parameter